# Exception for Python ftplib in my program?

Tags: python

I wrote this program to draw data from a text file on a website's directory (of which is edited by the user on the site) but it seems to crash. A lot.

```
from sys import argv
import ftplib
import serial
from time import sleep

one = "0"
repeat = True

ser = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600)

while repeat == True:
     path = 'public_html/'
     filename = 'fileone.txt'
     ftp = ftplib.FTP("*omitted*")
     ftp.login("*omitted*", "*omitted*")
     ftp.cwd(path)
     ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + filename ,open(filename, 'wb').write)
     ftp.quit()

     txt = open(filename)

     openup = txt.read()

     ser.write(openup)
     print(openup)
```

Does anyone know any kind of way to stop it from crashing? I was thinking of using an exception but I'm no Python expert. The program does what it's meant to do, by the way, and the address and login have been omitted for obvious reasons. Also if possible I ask for an exception to stop the program from crashing when it disconnects from the serial port.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Catch a `ftplib.Error` if it is ftplib related, if not catch whatever errors you might expect

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You might want to put all the ftplib related code in a try-except block like so:

```
try:
    #code related to ftplib
except Exception, e:  #you can fill this in after you encounter the exception once
    print str(e)
```

2. You seem to be opening the file but not closing it when you're done. This might also cause errors later. The best way to do this would be:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as txt:
    openup = txt.read()
```

This way the file will be closed automatically once you're outside the 'with' block.